# Not able to download ARM EABI 7a system image for Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, sdk, download, android-virtual-device

I am not able to install arm eabi system 7a system image for android 4.4
I am getting this while trying to install from sdk:

```
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 23.0.5
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 403
Downloading Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 403
Downloading Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 403
Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 403
Downloading Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 403
Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 403
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I tried installing it offline.I downloaded the zip file from :
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sysimg_wear_arm-20_r02.zip
Then I copied the .zip file in the temp folder of my sdk directory.But still it tries to install the system image from the internet and gives the same error as mentioned above.
Without the arm system image file I am not able to create an avd and hence not able to proceed.
Any idea how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy the sdk folder from any other computer and paste it in yours. Don't forget, in Eclipse, give it the path of this copied folder.